# Javascript input value rounded down

Tags: javascript

Quick Question:

I'm developing a little app for my friends who trade crypto's.  I'm new to javascript and I have a little math equation that works, but it doesn't calculate decimals!!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8">

function output(){
var dollarbit = document.getElementById('dollarbit').value;
var kdperdollar = document.getElementById('kdperdollar').value;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = (parseInt(kdperdollar) / (parseInt(dollarbit) * 1000));
}


</script>


    <title>Bit X-Change</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
    You Paid:
$<input id="dollarbit" type="text" /> Per Bitcoin 
<br />
You Paid: 
$<input id="kdperdollar" type="text" />
(Per Thousand Doge)(IE 1.88) <br />

Do not enter dollar signs <br />
<input type="submit" onclick="output();">
<br />
Value of Each Doge = <p id="result"> </p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

What do I need to add to the Javascript to make it include decimals? That's pretty important here =P

Thanks Guys! 
Much Love,
Pat

EDIT: Also: You can see it live here: http://www.shiftedrecording.com/shiftedaudio/TippedTest/bit.php
Notice the value only changes on whole integers =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `parseInt` -- which rounds, if you want decimals, use `parseFloat` or `parseDouble`

Comment: When using parseInt - always use `parsetInt(someVar, 10)` instead of just `parseInt(someVar)`

Answer (score 1):

Just use `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt()`. Floats are decimal numbers in computer-speak, Ints are, well, integers (so a decimal number will be rounded to the next integer if you use `parseInt`)

Comment: @ Pavel Nikolov @ tymeJV Thanks for the help!